# ERROR. Database query getting added to multiple lists simultaneously

Tags: java, android, mysql, list, sqlite

Database Name : "events".
I want to add the data of all rows belonging to "name","status","numbers"  attribute of table event to different lists tmp1,tmp2,tmp3 respectively.
I have the following code

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

FrameLayout frame;
RecyclerView recList;
TextView BlankDB;
private SQLiteDatabase datab;
public ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();


public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    frame = (FrameLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.frame);

    if(checkDataBase()) {
        recList = new RecyclerView(getActivity());
        recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

        //Getting the elements from DB
        ArrayList<String> tmp1 = getListofevents("events", "name");
        ArrayList<String> tmp2 = getListofstatus("events","status");
        ArrayList<String> tmp3 = getListofmembers("events", "numbers");
        for(int i=0;i<tmp3.size();i++){
            Log.e("The length of tmp1 is: ", String.valueOf(tmp1.get(i)));
            Log.e("The length of tmp2 is: ", String.valueOf(tmp2.get(i)));
            Log.e("The length of tmp3 is: ", String.valueOf(tmp3.get(i)));


        }

      //  String[] array4 = tmp4.toArray(new String[tmp4.size()]);
        Log.e("The length of tmp1 is: ", String.valueOf(tmp1.size()));

        ContactAdapter ca = new ContactAdapter(tmp1);
        recList.setAdapter(ca);
        frame.addView(recList);
    }

    else{
        BlankDB = new TextView(getActivity());
        BlankDB.setText("There is no event to display");
        BlankDB.setTextSize(40);
        frame.addView(BlankDB);
    }
    return v;
}

private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(getActivity().getDatabasePath("events").toString(), null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        checkDB.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database doesn't exist yet.
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}


public ArrayList<String> getListofevents(String evName,String attribute) {

    datab = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase(evName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Cursor crs = datab.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM event", null);

    while(crs.moveToNext()){
        String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(attribute));
        Log.e("The string is : ", uname);
        array.add(uname);
    }
    crs.close();
    datab.close();
    return array;
}

public ArrayList<String> getListofstatus(String evName,String attribute) {

    datab = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase(evName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Cursor crs = datab.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM event", null);

    while(crs.moveToNext()){
        String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(attribute));
        Log.e("The string is : ", uname);
        array.add(uname);
    }
    crs.close();
    datab.close();
    return array;
}

public ArrayList<String> getListofmembers(String evName,String attribute) {

    datab = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase(evName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Cursor crs = datab.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM event", null);

    while(crs.moveToNext()){
        String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(attribute));
        Log.e("The string is : ", uname);
        array.add(uname);
    }
    crs.close();
    datab.close();
    return array;
}
```

}

But the problem is that all the lists are getting all the data that is selected by all queries. The table event has the following data

"name" : dinner , abcd

"status" : Yes, Yes

"number" : 1 , 1

But the log generated as the result of compilation shows

```
04-06 23:33:59.023 2302-2302/? E/The string is :: dinner
04-06 23:33:59.023 2302-2302/? E/The string is :: abcd
04-06 23:33:59.024 2302-2302/? E/The string is :: Yes
04-06 23:33:59.024 2302-2302/? E/The string is :: Yes
04-06 23:33:59.024 2302-2302/? E/The string is :: 1
04-06 23:33:59.024 2302-2302/? E/The string is :: 1
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp1 is:: dinner
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp2 is:: dinner
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp3 is:: dinner
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp1 is:: abcd
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp2 is:: abcd
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp3 is:: abcd
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp1 is:: Yes
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp2 is:: Yes
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp3 is:: Yes
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp1 is:: Yes
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp2 is:: Yes
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp3 is:: Yes
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp1 is:: 1
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp2 is:: 1
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp3 is:: 1
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp1 is:: 1
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp2 is:: 1
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp3 is:: 1
04-06 23:33:59.029 2302-2302/? E/The length of tmp1 is:: 6
```

I am new to android. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same instance 'array' to handle all your Selects.
This causes your ‘temp instances’ (1,2,3) to hold all the data that array has, because they use the same reference.

Example:

```
public ArrayList<String> getListofevents(String evName,String attribute) {

    ArrayList<String> arrAux = new ArrayList<String>();

    datab = getActivity().openOrCreateDatabase(evName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Cursor crs = datab.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM event", null);

    while(crs.moveToNext()){
                String uname = crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex(attribute));
          Log.e("The string is : ", uname);
          arrAux.add(uname);
     }
     crs.close();
     datab.close();


    return arrAux;
}
```